# shorter way to write code - section visibility on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(".link1").click(function(){
 $(".slide2, .slide3, .slide4, .slide5").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide1").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link2").click(function(){
 $(".slide1, .slide3, .slide4, .slide5").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide2").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link3").click(function(){
 $(".slide2, .slide1, .slide4, .slide5").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide3").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link4").click(function(){
 $(".slide2, .slide3, .slide1, .slide5").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide4").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link5").click(function(){
 $(".slide2, .slide3, .slide4, .slide1").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide5").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
```

```css
.slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide4, .slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}

.link1, .link2, .link3, .link4, .link5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 133px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.thumbWrapper{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="thumbWrapper">
      <div><a href="#" class="link1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578491133524-f33d9c7a7484?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1023&q=80" width="100"></a></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="link2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587279063133-e65e2d8b849f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" width="100" ></a></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="link3 w-inline-block"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587666146633-78b032acb7c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" width="100" ></a></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="link4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587744709903-eb66fb650b8e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80" width="100" ></a></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="link5"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543340771-9530d5b94554?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" width="100" ></a></div>
    </div>
       </div>
<div>
  <div class="slide1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578491133524-f33d9c7a7484?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1023&q=80" width="200" ></div>
  <div class="slide2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587279063133-e65e2d8b849f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" width="200" ></div>
  <div class="slide3"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587666146633-78b032acb7c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" width="200" ></div>
  <div class="slide4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587744709903-eb66fb650b8e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80" width="200" ></div>
  <div class="slide5"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543340771-9530d5b94554?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" width="200" ></div>
  </div>
```

I will have 40 diferent thumbs and 40 large images that i placed all on absolute with opacity set to zero.
On thumb click image should fade in. I started some code and is working (just 5 links) but it seems to me there must be shorter way to do this for my 40 links... Any ideas?

Thank you!!!

I wrote this so far:

```js
<script>
$(".link2").click(function(){
 $(".slide11, .slide1, .slide3, .slide44, .slide55, .slide66").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide2").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link1").click(function(){
 $(".slide2, .slide1, .slide3, .slide44, .slide55, .slide66").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide11").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link3").click(function(){
 $(".slide11, .slide1, .slide2, .slide44, .slide55, .slide66").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide3").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link4").click(function(){
 $(".slide11, .slide1, .slide3, .slide2, .slide55, .slide66").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide44").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  $(".link5").click(function(){
 $(".slide11, .slide1, .slide3, .slide44, .slide2, .slide66").css("opacity", 0.0);
$(".slide55").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add an example of your markup as well please? There will be an easier way to do this, seeing the markup will help in developing an approach. Thanks!

Comment: [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better suited for this kind of questions

Comment: @json tnx! I edited the markup in post

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to attach the click event listener to the parent of your links e.g.

```
<div id="thumbs-container">
    // links with ids like link1, link2 go here
</div>
```

And, have consistent id and classes for links and slides, respectively i.e.
`#link4` will correspond to `.slide4`. Then:

```
var LINK_PREFIX = "link";
var SLIDE_CLASS_PREFIX = ".slide";

var totalSlides = 40;
var slides = [];

for (var slideNum = 1; slideNum <= totalSlides;  slideNum++) {
    slides.push(SLIDE_CLASS_PREFIX + slideNum);
}

var container = document.getElementById("thumbs-container");

container.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    var targetId = event.target.id;

    if (targetId.indexOf(LINK_PREFIX) === -1) return; // optional check: not clicked on any link
    var slideNum = targetId.replace(LINK_PREFIX, "");

    var slideToFadeIn = SLIDE_CLASS_PREFIX + slideNum;
    var slidesToHide = slides.filter(slide => slide !== slideToFadeIn);

    $(slidesToHide.join(", ")).css("opacity", 0.0);
    $(slideToFadeIn).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to be more declaritive in your approach. Consider the following, which also offers two different ways of thinking about the animation.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('disp')
c.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.showOne div.active')
          .forEach( el => el.classList.remove('active'))
  event.target.classList.add('active')
})
```

```css
.showOne div {
  opacity: 30%;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
.showOne div:hover {
  animation: anim-fade 1s ease;
  color: green;
}
.showOne div.active {
  color: red;
  opacity: 100%;
}

@keyframes anim-fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 30%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="disp" class="showOne">
  <div> AAAA </div>
  <div> BBBB </div>
  <div> CCCC </div>
  <div> DDDD </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can apply a single click event, get the parent of the clicked element, load the index of the parent element among the children of the grandparent element, so we know which item needs to be shown and we hide its siblings:

```
$(".thumbWrapper > div > a").click(function() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    $(".slide" + ([...parent.parentNode.children].indexOf(parent) + 1)).fadeTo("slow", 1.0).siblings().css("opacity", 0.0);
})
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that if you change the structure of the code, this will break, as it's dependent on the structure as you stated. Personally, I think using the same class and passing the event would be a smarter way, as you could use it anywhere in your markup and not run the risk of it breaking.

Comment: @Jsan23 What Joel refers to is that we use a selector here for the click event and the inner code of the event assumes that the anchor is inside the div which is inside the container of the divs. I think his point is that you could use the same class for a link and its corresponding picture, while you use a class for links and another for pictures. It is possible to do it that way as well, however, my solution works for you without refactoring your HTML. His suggestion involves refactoring your HTML as well.

Comment: I think you can use the current solution now and worry about structure change when/if it happens. However, as Joel Hager suggests, structural changes will render this solution non-functional, so you may want to revisit this later.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to do the same (i put notes inside):

```js
// just for demo - create 40 images and append them to DOM:
var i = 1;
while (i < 41) {
  var sliderEl = document.createElement("img"); 
  sliderEl.setAttribute('class','slider'); 
  sliderEl.setAttribute('src','https://via.placeholder.com/200x60.png?text=demoIMG'+i);
  sliderEl.addEventListener('click', showImg); // this would trigger on click 
  document.body.appendChild(sliderEl); 
  ++i;
}

// clicking one of the images will execute this function:
function showImg() {
  var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
  for (var i=0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
    sliders[i].removeAttribute('style');
  }
  this.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; top: calc(50vh - 100px)  ; left: calc(50vw - 100px); transform: scale(2,2);');
};
```

```css
.slider {display: block; border: 1px solid black; margin: 20px;}
```

This would be quicker to set and manipulate. Enjoy Code!